# Output buffering not rendering php content

Tags: php

I have a template controller. In this controller I load the appropriate template with `require_once` like this:

```
ob_start();
$userInfo = $user->userDetails($_SESSION["userId"]);
require_once('/templates/1/file1.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

File1.php (the file being "required" in the template controller) needs access to `$userInfo` however, it does not. Am I doing something wrong with the output buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your `require_once` is failing because the path to the template file is incorrect.

It should probably be something like:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates/1/file1.php');
```

or

```
require_once($global_template_path . '/templates/1/file1.php');
```

where `$global_template_path` is something like `/home/yoursite/app/module`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It actually is `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates/1/file1.php');` I just trimmed it down for brevity. The weird thing is that the HTML within file1.php loads and is output by the output buffer, but the php does not

Comment: Can you post what is in file1.php in that case?

Comment: It's just HTML with a few php loops such as `foreach($userInfo as $info)` It errors out saying "Invalid parameter in foreach on line xx" It's referring to `$userInfo` which is defined in my template controller. thanks!

Comment: Is the call to $userInfo in the template in the global scope or within a function or class?  Your example works for me in a simple test

Comment: Oh damn. I just saw my mistake. I didn't call `session_start();`. Sigh... Stupid mistake on my part. Sorry to waste your time. Thanks for helping!